# How to change fillColor due a field value

Tags: spring-roo, legend-properties, gvnix

I have a map with some features, but I want to shoe them depending on al field.

May be

if [fieldname] = 0 --> color = RED
else  --> color = blue

Could anyone give a clue where to start?

Searching at leaflet documentation I managed to program

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d = 0 ? '#3182bd' :
           d = 1 ? '#31a354' :
                    '#FFEDA0';
}

function style(feature) {
return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.*fieldname*),
    };

}
```

But I'm not sure how to integer it, if I'm on the way or there's something easier with gvnix

Thanks all
Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gvNIX view you can customize the symbol used to draw a geometry using the attribute [`fnAjustRender`](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/geo/layers/entity-field.tagx#L11) of `entity-field` *tagx*. Using this method you must declare a `script` in *.jspx* page and register it in the attribute.

By example, in [show.jspx entity fied definition](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/map/show.jspx#L35) you should change:

```
....
<layer:entity-field clusterize="false" 
        fnAjustRender="myJSFunction"   .... z="user-managed"/>
....
```

Then create a `myJSFunction` in *jspx* like this:

```
<script>
  function myJSFunction(gvmap, layerId, fieldName, 
       featurePk, leafletLayer, featureData, isSelected) {

      var iconColor = "white";
      if (featureData.propName == 1) {
        iconColor = "red";
      } else {
        iconColor = "blue";
      }
      var iconMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                "icon" : icon,
                "prefix" : prefix,
                "markerColor" : markerColor,
                "iconColor" : iconColor
            });
       leafletLayer.setIcon(iconMarker);
       return leafletLayer;
  }

</script>
```

*Warning: no tested code*

Good luck!